# Unit Test in Wordpress

Tags: php, unit-tests

I work in wordpress with a lot of classes that use wordpress functions and I'd like make unit tests for them. The problem I found is that phpunit doesn't recognize wordpress functions and the tests don't work.

I tried to include in the test class the index.php, wp-load.php and when  they are included, phpunit doesn't work and exits through "exit code 0" without do anything -the error is shown in the PhpStorm Terminal. If I execute the command in the cmd, the cmd doesn't throw any information, just a blank line.

Php Version: 7.3.3
PhpUnit Version: 7.5.9
Wordpress Version: 4.9.1

An example of an error is to test for a class with "add_action" in their constructor and the error is: "Call to undefined function add_action()". I don't know what file I have to include for doing work this test or what is the method to test the class correctly.

Comment: Start here https://brain-wp.github.io/BrainMonkey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the WordPress core setup with PHPUnit: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/phpunit/

Using this process rather than rolling your own allows you to leverage the boostrapping (and other customization) specific for WordPress.

From the [Codex](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/writing-phpunit-tests/#the-wordpress-installation-and-bootstrap):

> When `phpunit` is invoked, the test suite runs a script that sets up a
>   default installation of WordPress, with a configuration similar to
>   what you get with the GUI install. Before any tests are run, the
>   following steps take place:
>
> - WordPress is bootstrapped (by including `wp-settings.php`). This means that all tests run after the entire WP bootstrap (through `wp_loaded`).
> - All default content is deleted. This includes sample posts and pages, but does not include the default user or the ‘Uncategorized’ category.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just install the wordpress core setup with phpunit following the documentation and now the problem is that phpunit doesn't recognize wordpress function i don't understand it. The last test say "Call to undefined functions get_network()" in "wp-includes/functions.php". I need to include some wordpress file or something?
Thanks again!

Comment: That's a multisite function. You need to configure PHPUnit to work with multisite. Here's a good intro: http://www.codetab.org/tutorial/wordpress-plugin-development/unit-test/multisite-plugin-unit-tests/

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend [wp-browser](https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser) for that task.

https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser

I've already written tests for entire websites, for .org plugins and premium plugins using wp-browser. It has unit, integration (same as Core's PHPUnit setup), acceptance (like with a Selenium server) and functional servers out of the box, all designed and architected to work with WordPress.